# Validar input con un radio button angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, formularios

Tengo este radio button que es obligatorio

[image: Estado falso]

que tiene dos valores uno true y false cuando el valor es true me debe salir un input

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es como valido ese input cuando el radio sea true, en pocas palabras lo vuelvo requerido

lo estaba validando así, cuando envió el formulario, pero quiero hacerlo antes de enviarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Mira esto a ver [Ejemplo en StackBliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vhp2ud?embed=1&file=src/app/radio-overview-example.html&view=editor).

lo que hace el ejemplo es que cuando le das "Si" el input que aparece se vuelve requerido, pero cuando le das "No" el mismo se le debe quitar que sea requerido.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo había resulto, así justamente.

Answer (score 0):

Podes hacerlo usando *ngIf en el input,

```html
<input *ngIf="radiobutton == true>;
```

esto se va a mostar cuando la variable del radio button este en true, podes hacerlo con el valor que quieras. Espero te sirva

Comment: No, me entendiste muy bien la idea es volver el campo requerido solo cuando el valor sea true, y si no lo llena no deje enviar